# Django - Make query to another table from count result

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

This is a question on the most effective way to make a 2-step query, where the output on the first one is the input on the second one...

I have this Model.

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    service_request = models.ForeignKey(ServiceRequest, null=True)
    split_request = models.ForeignKey(SplitRequest, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    lesson_fee = models.ForeignKey(LessonFee, null=True)
    stripe_token = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)

class ServiceRequest(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    ....
    hours = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Currently, i have the following queryset in views.py:

```
payments = Payment.objects.values('service_request').annotate(dsum=Sum('amount')).annotate(dcount=Count('service_request')).order_by('dcount')
```

Which gives something like the following result:

```
service_request   dcount  dsum
...
177     1   31.2    
202     1   31.2    
205     1   31.2    
197     1   31.2    
187     1   62.1    
174     2   6.24    
155     3   74.52   
209     4   46.4
```

As you can see, i get 5 rows having 1 as the count value. I want to do some aggregations to this resultset, like summing the dsum column for repeated dcount rows, and also summing the 'hours' field that can be found on the *ServiceRequest* table on a new column.

I thought of looping through each row of the resultset, querying for each *service_request_pk*, but that would be super inefficient.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a join between the two models.

Here is the [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) for it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can take your resultant queryset and apply groupby will give you the result as expected.

`grouped_payments_iterator = itertools.groupby(payments,dcount)`

Since payments is already sorted on dcount, groupby should work fine.